# Why i don't have the namespace text to speech in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;


namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I could make using Android.Speech.Tts but after Tts there is nothing.
Maybe I need to download api using the Android SDK Manager ? There is a lot of things to download there should I download them all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TextToSpeech](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech/) is a class, not a namespace.  If you have `Android.Speech.Tts` declared with a `using` statement, you should be able to create an instance of `TextToSpeech` within your class.

See the [TextToSpeech](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/speech/) sample for a complete example.